# AngularJS Dropdown results vanish on select

Tags: angularjs

Have tried the following example in AngularjS but for some reason the results vanish

Step 1 >>> The results from JSON show up in Dropdown.

Step 2 >>> I select First element from the dropdown.

Step 3 >>> On selecting the first element from dropdown, the first value vanishes and dropdown also contains only one element.

Code to achieve the same was as shown below.

```
<div ng-controller="ProductsListController">
                          <br>
                          <br>
                              <div ng-show="products.length">
                                  <div>
                                      <select ng-model="products" ng-options="product for product in products">
                                      <option value="">Select Account</option>
                                      </select>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
```

app.js code

```
angular.module('displayProductList').controller('ProductsListController', function($scope, $http) {
    console.log("Entered in app.js .... ");
    $scope.fetchProductsList = function() {
        console.log("Entered in app.js : fetchProductsList");
            $http.get('/guardian/springmvc/products/productlist.json').success(function(productslist){
            console.log("Entered in app.js : before scope.products");
            $scope.products = productslist;
            console.log("Entered in app.js : after scope.products" + productslist);
        });
    };
    console.log("Before fetch");
    $scope.fetchProductsList();
    console.log("After fetch", $scope.products)
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `ng-model` set to the value of the array (ie. both are set to `products`). As a result, once a selection is made, the selected value overwrites the original value of the array.

These two values need to differ:

```
<select ng-model="product" ng-options="product for product in products">
```